# Phpmailer Add Bcc not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using Phpmailer to send mail. It is working perfectly except for the bcc. The Bcc recipient could not see the cc and the to. Why is this happening?

```
require_once("PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php");
            $mailer = new PHPMailer();
            $mailer->IsSMTP();

            $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";

            $mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mailer->Port = 587;            

            $mailer->Username = $userid;
            $mailer->Password = $epwd;
            $mailer->FromName = $fromname;
            $mailer->From = $userid;
            $mailer->AddAddress($to,$toname);
            $mailer->Subject = $subject;                
            $mailer->Body =$content;                
            $mailer->AddCC($cc, $tocc);             
            $mailer->AddBCC($bcc, $tobcc);          
            $mailer->AddAttachment($dest_filename);
            $mailer->Send()
```

Comment: $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mailer->Port = 587;  
    $mailer->Username = $userid;
    $mailer->Password = $epwd;
    $mailer->FromName = $fromname;
    $mailer->From = $userid;                                                               $mailer->AddAddress($to,$toname);    
    $mailer->Subject = $subject;    
    $mailer->Body =$content;    $mailer->AddCC($cc);    $mailer->AddBCC($bcc); 
                            $mailer->Send()

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance this is a gmail issue.
Did you test with another SMTP service provider?

Answer (score 0):

From class.phpmailer.php:

```
/**
  * Adds a "Bcc" address. Note: this function works<br>
  * with the SMTP mailer on win32, not with the "mail"<br>
  ...
 */
function AddBCC($address, $name = '') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The question is so vague that's impossible to know what's wrong, but this answer does not add any useful info.